# in Dart, problems when attempting to "register" sub-class with super-class

Tags: dart

I wish to have the `sub-classes` of a `super-class` "registered" by an arbitrary name - whenever I declare a `sub-class` I wish to also have it entered into the `super-class.sub` Map.

Is there any way to accomplish this outside of `main()`?

```dart
// base class
class Mineral{
  final String formula;
  static Map<String,Mineral> sub = {}
  Mineral( this.formula );
}

// sub class - declare and register
class Mica extends Mineral{
  Mica( String formula ) : super( formula );
}
Mineral.sub['mica'] = Mica;  // oops!
```

when I run this, I get

```
Error: line 10 pos 1: unexpected token 'Mineral' Mineral.sub['mica'] = Mica;
```

assuming that executable code is not allowed outside `main()`.

cannot put within the `super-class` since other `sub-classes` may declared later, outside the library.

Comment: I'm curious what you wanted to accomplish with `Mineral.sub['mica'] = Mica;` in the first place, as `Mica` is no instance and would result in an type error. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart has no way to run code as part of a library being loaded.
Executable code can only be put inside methods, or in field initializers, and static field initializers are lazy so they won't execute any code until you try to read them.

This is done to ensure quick startup - a Dart program doesn't have to execute any code before starting the main library's "main" method.

So, no, there is no way to initialize something that isn't constant before main is called.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```dart
Mineral.sub['mica'] = new Mica();
```

or

```dart
static Map<String,Type> sub = {};
```

When you assign `Mica` you assign the Type `Mica`. `new Mica()` is an instance of Mica that is of the kind Mineral and can be assigned to the map you declared.

**edit**

Maybe you want to initialize the sub map:

```dart
static Map<String,Mineral> sub = {'mica': new Mica()};
```

hint: the semicolon is missing in this line in your question.

Comment: the problem is that neither `Mineral.sub['mica'] = Mica;` nor `Mineral.sub['mica'] = new Mica();` can be declared in the library.  am I making sense?

Comment: You want to do this outside of a function. Why do you want/need this?